# Another absolute import problem

Tags: python

I'm having problems with my own modules overriding built in Python ones (specifically the logging module).  Here's my project layout:

```
run.py
package/
        __init__.py
        logging/
                __init__.py
        ...
```

run.py

```
from package import main

main()
```

package/__init__.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import logging
import logging.config

def main():
    logging.config.fileConfig(...)
```

package/logging/__init__.py

```
class Logging(object):
    pass
```

As it stands right now, the above code works.  As soon as I try to import the Logging class from package.logging like so:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import logging
import logging.config
from package.logging import Logging

def main():
    logging.config.fileConfig(...)
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'
```

I've read the [PEP 328](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) release notes and found absolute imports to be rather straightforward.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this one out.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9):

Relative and absolute imports (PEP 328) are not the problem here.

What happens is that when a module in a package is imported, it is implicitly added to this package's namespace. So

```
from package.logging import Logging
```

not only adds 'Logging' to package.*_dict*_, but also adds 'logging' (the newly import local module) to package.*_dict*_. So you first import logging (the top-level module) and it is available as package.logging, and then you overwrite this variable with the local module. This basically means that you cannot have a package.logging to access the top-level module and your local module, as expected.

In this specific case, you probably don't want to "export" the top-level logging module as a public name. Instead do:

```
from logging import config as _config
def main():
    _config.fileConfig(...)
```

Comment: Wow, just learned a new Python gotcha. I needed to test this myself and it is exactly as you say. If someone else wants to verify this, just add `print logging` after `from package.logging import Logging`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328) to force where python looks for the modules first:

`in package/__init__.py`

```
from . import logging
```

Comment: using your example does appear to work.  However, I now have to refer to the Logging class as logging.Logging.  Further testing reveals that "from .logging import Logging" does not appear to work as PEP 328 suggests.  I still don't understand why "from package.logging import Logging" doesn't work.  Isn't it an absolute import?

Comment: what version of python are you using?  If its an older version (say 2.4) the relative imports may not work, or at least, not work as expected.

Comment: I just verified that this problem also affects Python 2.5.2